# Why does the background-image property in css not working?

Tags: html, css

So, I'm planning to give a div a background image.

Here's the path for the picture i want to use :

```
website\images\logo.png
```

And here's the path for the html and css file :

```
website/index.html
```

```
website/style.css
```

Here's the html code :

```
<header>
   <div class="logo"></div>
</header>
```

Here's the css code :

```
header .logo {
    width: 45px;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: url('../images/logo.png');
}
```

But the image still won't display in the background of the div and instead I get this error when i inspect and click the consol tab :

```
Not allowed to load local resource:
```

I also tried different variations such as :

```
background-image: url(../images/logo.png);
background-image: url(./images/logo.png);
background-image: url('./images/logo.png');
background-image: url('/images/logo.png');
background-image: url(/images/logo.png);
background-image: url('images/logo.png');
background-image: url(images/logo.png);
```

and all of them doesn't seem to work

I also tried to give the div a background color and it seems to work just fine.

What is the solution? Thank you

Comment: Can you try to reproduce the same issue in your question using snippet. Also, what kind of image is that ? I mean what is the size of it? Try giving `background-size: cover`. Let's see if something comes up

Comment: share the screenshot of the directory, also the <header> code

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the issue with getting source from localhost, if you are using VScode then try installing this extension called `Live Server`  May be, it could fix the issue. take a look: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer